# Return Column Header of Colored Cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This process is being used for QC purposes. I have a spreadsheet that highlights certain cells that are wrong based off of their values and the validation rules we have in place. I was wonder if there was a way to return the column names of each cell that is colored into column A for each row? So for example if  D2, F2, and G2 are wrong it would put all of those column headers in A2 to specify what exactly is wrong. I know it gets a bit more complicated trying to automate stuff with cell colors and I am not experienced in VBA which I'm assuming this will need. Is this possible to do, if so what would be the proper route to take? The data runs from column A to column BS, and the row numbers may differ, so if it could run up to row 1,000 that would be great. Attached is what the data looks like that I am working with.

[The red means something is wrong in that row, and the orange cell is the color indicating that it is a wrong value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQX2f.png)

Comment: The only question you asked is: *Is this possible to do?*. That answer is yes. If you want more help than that, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with some more clarity, brevity and code.

Comment: Why not focus on the values and the validation rules rather than on the colors per se? It is easier to target logic rather than color. By focusing on the logic you might not need VBA at all.

Comment: I figured it would be easier to go off of cell color because different values may be acceptable based on other values. So I think with the various combination that it would be easier to go off of cell color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do. Here is some snippets of code I pulled together to help get you started.

```
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Get last row
With ActiveSheet
Lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Get last col
End With 

 For x = 1 To Lastcol 'Iterate Col    
        For i = 1 To Lastrow 'Iterate Row   
            'if red....
            If Cells(i, x).Selection.Interior.Color = 255 then
               'Move name to Cell A and append off of old name(s).
               Cells(i, "A") = Cells(i, "A") & ", " & Cells(i, x)
            End If    
        Next i 'next row
    Next x 'next col
```

Comment: dv - because even though you say psuedo-code, it's not actually psuedo-code, but actually pretty sloppy code.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, its a start, I'm not writing the code for him. Its a start from previous code I pulled together. If you have a better/cleaner answer than mine. Please submit it and share as this is a step further than just telling him "Yes".